# LG E-615 и Linux

Tags: настройки

как установить PC sync на компьютер с ОС Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Я нечто подобное делал через VirtualBox, с установленной там WinXP, с пробросом USB. Старый Сименс был, дров под ничего, кроме ХРюши не было... Ну, получилось, однако!